# Perform character replacement/removal on only one column of a delimited file?

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I have a csv file which has two columns, a numeric ID (`IDVAR`) and an associated value (`VAL`). The second variable contains non-alphabetic garbage characters which need cleaning up. The structure looks like this:

```
IDVAR   VAL
001     abc - 1
002     zfas $^6
003     asdf_78
004     hg :65
```

I want to throw out the `"-", "_", "1", "$", "^"` etc. from the 2nd variable only, i.e. remove a specified set of characters from `VAL`, without touching `IDVAR`.

Post-Solution Edit: Many thanks to SiegeX for such an elegant solution. Please note that my file is indeed comma-separated, so I just have to add an "-F," option to his awk command.

Comment: That doesn't look much like comma-separated values, which is what CSV stands for.  It looks like it might be tabs or blanks separating the columns.

Comment: To Jon's point, what exactly *is* the field separator?

Comment: Yes, my bad. The original file is indeed csv, but when I copied an pasted here, the double quotes and commas didn't show up. Not sure why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work for you:

```
awk 'NR>1{t=$1;gsub(/[^[:alpha:]]/,"");$0=t "\t" $0}1' file
```

#### Example

```
$ awk 'NR>1{t=$1;gsub(/[^[:alpha:]]/,"");$0=t "\t" $0}1' file
IDVAR   VAL
001     abc
002     zfas
003     asdf
004     hg
```

#### Explanation

1. `NR>1` : Skip the header row containing `IDVAR    VAL`
2. `t=$1` : Save the first field (IDVAR) into temporary variable 't'
3. `gsub(/[^[:alpha:]]/,"")` : Regex that says to replace all *non*-alphanumeric characters with the empty string.  Note `gsub()` applies to the entire line which is why we used 't' above
4. `$0=t "\t" $0` : Prepend the variable 't' to the beginning of the line separated by a tab
5. `1` : Awk shortcut for *print $0* since '1' is always true and the default behavior for a true statement when not explicitly specified is to print the current line.

Comment: Thanks, SiegeX. This is ALMOST working. Somehow it's creating a third variable which is separated from VAL by tabs. What gives?

Comment: Ahh... got it. I just need to add a "-F," option to awk. Solved. Many thanks, all of you folks.

Comment: @SiegeX , can you explain this a bit. New to awk and trying to understand your solution.

Comment: i think that you do not have to use temporary variable at all. At least now you can use `gsub(/[^[:alpha:]]/,"",$NUMBER_OF_COLUMN_TO_PROCESS)`

Comment: @Dominik the problem is `$NUMBER_OF_COLUMN_TO_PROCESS` is not a static number for each record; it depends on the contents of the record we are processing due to unwanted spaces.

Comment: @SiegeX I think that it is not stated explicitly in the question, is it? Anyway your solution was very helpfull for me :) thx.

Answer (score 1):

```
cut -f1 -d, foo > foo.firstColumn
cut -f2 -d, foo \
    | sed 's/[-_1$^]//g' \
    | paste foo.firstColumn - \
    > foo.stripped
rm foo.firstColumn
```

Comment: I like this approach, very 'divide and conquer' and 'use the simplest tool for the job', even though it's not a neat one-liner like Awk.

Comment: I find `awk`, `perl` and similar one-liners easily build up complexity and become unmanageable in the long-term. UNIX allows piping, so we should use it where it makes sense, and I like reducing complexity and improving readability.

Comment: This will replace the characters in the header row. It will also fail, when the delimiter occurs in an escaped string.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Perl, but that's because I use Perl for many purposes of text-mangling like this.

```
perl -n -e 'chomp; my($f1,$f2) = $_ =~ m/(\S+)\s+(\S.*)/;
            $f2 =~ s/[-_\$^1]//g; print "$f1\t$f2\n";' file
```

Except on SO, that could be one line.  You have to be a little careful with `$`, `^` and `-`, but other characters can be added quite easily.

Give your sample input and the list of characters above to be eliminated, the output is:

```
IDVAR   VAL
001     abc  
002     zfas 6
003     asdf78
004     hg :65
```

Maybe 'such as' should have included blank, colon and the other digits?